# Discreteness of Pontryagin dual of compact abelian group

Tags: general-topology, harmonic-analysis, topological-groups, duality-theorems, locally-compact-groups

We have the following theorem:

> If $G$ is a compact (Hausdorff) group, then the Pontryagin dual $\widehat{G}$ is discrete.

Does this also imply that $\widehat{G}$ is countable? Or is it possible that, for example, $\widehat{G}$ is the unit circle $\mathbb{T}$ endowed with the discrete topology instead of the standard Euclidian topology? I could not think of any examples where $\widehat{G}$ is an uncountable discrete group.

Comment: By Pontryagin duality, the dual of $G$ satisfies $(\hat G)^\wedge\cong G$. In particular, the dual of $\mathbb{T}$ with the discrete topology satisfies $\hat G\cong \mathbb{T}$.

Comment: @MaoWao Do you mean $\widehat{\mathbb{T}}\cong G$?

Comment: I mean that if $\widehat{\mathbb{T}}\cong G$, then $\hat G\cong \mathbb{T}$ (with the discrete topology on $\mathbb{T}$). So it's easy to produce an example whose Pontryagin dual is a given LCA group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there are uncountable discrete roups, just as there are non-metrizable compact groups.

Start with any non-metrizable compact group.  Its dual is an uncountable discrete group.

Example.  "The Tubby Torus"
Let
$$
G = \mathbb T^\Gamma
$$
where $\mathbb T$ is the unit circle, and $\Gamma$ is an uncountable set.  Use the usual topology and group structure for $\mathbb T$, and use the product group structure and product topology for $G$.  In fact, the dual $\widehat{G}$ is the uncountable direct sum
$$
\bigoplus_{\gamma \in \Gamma} \mathbb Z
$$
as a discrete group.

This works the other way, too.  Take any uncountable discrete group $D$, then $\widehat{D}$ is a non-metrizable compact group.

Comment: Just to put it more explicitly: for compact $G$, the discrete group $\hat{G}$ is countable iff $G$ is metrizable (=second countable).